# Get all publications by an author from Google Scholar using scholar.py

Tags: python, citations, google-scholar

I am trying to get all the publications by an author using scholar.py

https://github.com/ckreibich/scholar.py

But whenever I run the script, I only get a fraction of the publications associated with the author in my results.

So running:

```
./scholar.py --author "albert einstein"
```

Will only retrieve a subset of Einstein's 1000+ publications associated with him in Google Scholar. How can I get all of the publications for an author?

Comment: Do you only get 20 results?

Comment: From the docstring of `scholar.py`: `This module provides classes for querying Google Scholar and parsing
returned results. It currently *only* processes the first results
page. It is not a recursive crawler.`

Comment: @wflynny No, the number of results will vary depending on the researcher. I couldn't determine a pattern (like the first 20 results - but now it looks like that is what it is).

Comment: @Gerrat -- thanks for catching that! I totally missed that important little detail.

Comment: @AmberBilley I asked if you were only seeing 20 results because on line 1255 of `scholar.py`, there is this line:  `options.count = min(options.count, ScholarConf.MAX_PAGE_RESULTS)`  where `MAX_PAGE_RESULTS=20`.  Have you attempted to modify this constant?